# Scala rewriting type parameter of sub type in F-bounded polymorphism

Tags: scala, generics, types, polymorphism

I am trying to create a trait `Entity` which enforces its sub types to have 2 states: `Transient` and `Persistent`

```
trait EntityState
trait Transient extends EntityState
trait Persistent extends EntityState
trait Entity[State <: EntityState]
```

For example, a sub class, says `class Post[State <: EntityState] extends Entity[State]`, can be instantiated either as `new Post[Persistent]` or as `new Post[Transient]`.

Next, I am adding some methods to the trait `Entity` that can be called depending on its `State`:

```
trait Entity[State <: EntityState] {
    def id(implicit ev: State <:< Persistent): Long
    def persist(implicit ev: State <:< Transient): Entity[Persistent]
}
```

To explain, for any class that extends `Entity`, the method `id` can be called only when the class is of state `Persistent` (i.e. it has been saved to the database and already assigned an autogenerated id).

On the other hand, the method `persist` can be called only when the class is `Transient` (not yet saved to the database). The method `persist` is meant to save an instance of the caller class to the database and **return the `Persistent` version of the class.**

Now, the problem is **I would like that the return type of `persist` be that of the caller class**. For example, if I call `persist` on an instance of class `Post[Transient]`, it should return `Post[Persistent]` instead of `Entity[Persistent]`.

I searched around and found something called [F-Bounded Polymorphism](http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html#fbounded). I am trying many ways to adapt it to solve my problem but still not works. Here is what I did:

**First try:**

```
trait Entity[State <: EntityState, Self[_] <: Entity[State,Self]] {
    def id(implicit ev: State <:< Persistent): Long
    def persist(implicit ev: State <:< Transient): Self[Persistent]
}
```

and

```
class Post[State <: EntityState] extends Entity[State, ({type λ[B] == Post[State]})#λ] {

    def persist(implicit ev: <:<[State, Transient]): Post[State] = {
        ???
    }
}
```

In the class `Post` above, I use auto-completion of Eclipse to generate the implementation of the method `persist` and found that its return type is still incorrect.

**Second try:**

```
class Post[State <: EntityState] extends Entity[State, Post] {

   def persist(implicit ev: <:<[State, Transient]): Post[Persistent] = {
       ???
   }
}
```

with this, it seems correct, except it has a compilation error:

```
[error] D:\playspace\myblog\app\models\post\Post.scala:14: kinds of the type arguments (State,models.post.Post) do not conform to the expected kinds of the type parameters (type State,type Self) in trait Entity.
[error] models.post.Post's type parameters do not match type Self's expected parameters:
[error] type State's bounds <: common.models.EntityState are stricter than type _'s declared bounds >: Nothing <: Any
[error] trait Post[State <: EntityState] extends Entity[State, Post] {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you were trying to do:

```
trait Entity[State <: EntityState, Self[S<:EntityState] <: Entity[S, Self]] {
  _: Self[State] =>

    def id(implicit ev: State <:< Persistent): Long
    def persist(implicit ev: State <:< Transient): Self[Persistent]
}


abstract class Post[State <: EntityState] extends Entity[State, Post] {
   def persist(implicit ev: <:<[State, Transient]): Post[Persistent] = {
       ???
   }
}
```

**UPDATE:** The `_: Self[State] =>` part is a *self-type annotation*. It says that any class that mixes the `Entity` trait **must** extend `Self[State]` (not doing so would lead to a compile-time error). If we remove this self-type annotation, we might define something like this and the compiler would not blink an eye:

```
abstract class User[State <: EntityState] extends Entity[State, Post] {
   def persist(implicit ev: <:<[State, Transient]): Post[Persistent] = {
       ???
   }
}
```

Note how out `User` class extends `Entity` with the `Self` type parameter set to `Post` (instead of `User`). This is valid as far as the compiler is concerned, but was certainly not what you had in mind. 
With the self-type annotation, the above would not compile:

```
<console>:12: error: illegal inheritance;
 self-type User[State] does not conform to Entity[State,Post]'s selftype Post[State]
           abstract class User[State <: EntityState] extends Entity[State, Post] {
                                                             ^
```

Comment: Hi Régis.   What is this syntax`implicit ev: <:<[State, Transient]`?  Is that a typo or some syntax I don't know about?  It would be great to see some examples of this.

Comment: I just copied OP's code verbatim. This syntax is nothing special, it's the type `<:<`, applied to its two type parameters `State` and `Transient`. If anything, it's the other alternative (infix) syntax that is special and could be seen as syntactic sugar: `implicit ev: State <:< Transient` . See http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#infix-types

Comment: Hi Régis. I just try as you suggest and it works, except I did not put in the code `_: Self[State] =>`, could you please explain what it is, thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer to explain this. Needless to say, I advise to keep the self-type annotation.

Answer (score 2):

Why doesn't plain old ad-hoc polymorphism satisfy you here?  E.g., this compiles.

```
trait EntityState
trait Transient extends EntityState
trait Persistent extends EntityState
trait Entity[State <: EntityState] {
  def id(implicit ev: State <:< Persistent): Long
  def persist(implicit ev: State <:< Transient): Entity[Persistent]
}

class Post[State <: EntityState] extends Entity[State] {
  override def id(implicit ev: <:<[State, Persistent]): Long = 5
  override def persist(implicit ev: <:<[State, Transient]): Post[Persistent] = new Post[Persistent]
}

// compiles
val x: Post[Persistent] = (new Post[Transient]).persist
// doesn't compile, as desired
// val y = (new Post[Persistent]).persist
```

Comment: Yes, this is an option and I currently use it. But it has an inconvenience that we have to always redeclare `Entity`'s methods in the subtypes. In my actual code, I usually design the `Post` (and other entities) as a trait and have implementations elsewhere, And I have many methods in trait `Entity` that have to redeclare in those traits. I hope I could reduce these boilerplate.